# Equivalence between eigenvector matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Whilst using Mathematica to seek for eigenvectors, I get a slight different result from what I calculate manually. I know they are somehow equivalent, *I think*.

Take the matrix 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1&-1\\1&0&1\\-1&1&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Mathematica finds the following eigenvectors 
$$S_{math}=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1&1\\-1&0&1\\-1&-1&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Whilst my own calculations get it to

$$S_{own}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&1\\1&1&0\\-1&-1&-1\end{bmatrix}$$

How do I know if these two are equivalent? It's causing some trouble when I'm double checking if I've done my calculations correctly whilst practicing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica returns a list of eigenvectors, each of which is a list. If you turn this into matrix form, then the eigenvectors would be in rows. Taking the transpose of $S_{math}$ matches your result (up to scalings and permuting columns).

Comment: Could you add more on how scaling and permuting columns work?

Comment: Each eigenvector corresponds to an eigenvalue; the ordering of the columns depends on your (and Mathematica's) eigenvalue ordering. As far as scaling goes, an eigenvector multiplied by an scalar (possibly negative, complex, etc.) value is the same eigenvector; they're only defined up to scaling.